# Open url with parameters android

Tags: java, android, paypal

Hello I want to open a PayPal uri to pay from android.

And I want to open the web uri and add parmas. 
How do I do this ?

With an intent like this ?

```
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"));
            browserIntent.putExtra("param1","param1");
                            browserIntent.putExtra("param2","param2");
                            browserIntent.putExtra("param3","param3");
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to escape & concatenate a querystring?

Comment: What i want is to send data to the url, and then open it according the parameters. To get the screen in the android web browser to add the information of the user, like credit card, stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this.

```
String params = URLEncoder.encode("param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3", "utf-8");
String url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + params;

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: @user3170439 It's pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Bishan's solution was not working for me (`=` and `&` were incorrectly encoded).

This is a way to encode a URL with parameters:

```
Uri authUri = Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("param1", "value1")
                .appendQueryParameter("param2", "value2")
                .appendQueryParameter("param3", "value3")
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to pay with PayPal on Android would be using the native [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/).